# Timed out waiting for install to finish on Koji disk image build

Tags: centos7, openstack, koji

I am trying to build with Koji a [disk image](https://docs.pagure.org/koji/image_build/#building-disk-images) for CentOS7 that supports both BIOS and UEFI.  My problem is that while the following partitioning works during the build (even if it does not work when booting on a UEFI node):

```
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --disklabel gpt
# Disk partitioning information
part / --fstype="xfs" --size=1 --grow --asprimary
part biosboot --fstype=biosboot --size=1
# This is how upstream centos does it
part /boot/efi --fstype=vfat --grow --maxsize=200 --size=20

# Both UEFI AND BIOS cfg
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
```

The following doesn't, and all my partitioning changes end up with the bottom error.

```
# Disk partitioning information
part / --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=vda --size=3000 --mkfsoptions="-n ftype=1"
part biosboot --fstype=biosboot --size=1
# This is how upstream centos does it
part /boot/efi --fstype=vfat --grow --maxsize=200 --size=20
```

Error when building fails

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imgfac/Builder.py", line 132, in _build_image_from_template
    self.os_plugin.create_base_image(self, template, parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imagefactory_plugins/TinMan/TinMan.py", line 346, in create_base_image
    libvirt_xml = self.guest.install(self.app_config["timeout"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oz/RedHat.py", line 703, in install
    self.virtio_channel_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oz/Guest.py", line 1576, in _do_install
    self._wait_for_install_finish(xml, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oz/Guest.py", line 827, in _wait_for_install_finish
    raise oz.OzException.OzException("Timed out waiting for install to finish.  %s" % (screenshot_text))
OzException: Timed out waiting for install to finish.  Check screenshot at /var/builder/builder/tasks/2080/1692080/oz_screenshots/factory-build-51bd5b7d-4463-4bf9-9069-2f4b109a0165-1580480811.51.ppm for more detail
```

Is there any way I can check where it acutally times out? Any debugging with Koji? How would I test this ppm screenshot?